# Is it possible to create a two word enum in JDL?

Tags: jhipster

I want to define my enum in my JDL - with values that contain two or more space-delimited words - for (example) country names, like "United Kingdom", "Vatican City"

enum Country {
    Vatican City,United Kingdom
}

is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No as this is used to generate an enum name in java.

If you need this only for display purpose, you can just edit `src/main/webapp/i18n/en/Country.json` assuming you enabled internationalization.

Answer (score 0):

Gael answer should be flagged as the correct one. I would also add, for newcomers that wouldn't know what to put in the said JSONs that jHipster can generate them when you enable support for internationalization (I18N) when you generate your application.